# MIDI - Immediate release of note/voice?

Tags: midi

When sending a 'note off' message via MIDI the envelope is automatically placed into its release stage.

Is there a message I can send at this point that will force the note off immediately and ignore the remaining release stage time?

I would like the message to be standard MIDI so that it is compatible with all MIDI synthesizers.

Comment: This is a little technical for Super User, you may be better off on StackOverflow. Don't post on both sites, you can flag your question for moderator attn. and they can move it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything like this in the MIDI standard, because it's usually desirable to keep the note's tail. However, you can try sending a MIDI panic signal, which varies by device.

But in short, there's no way to do this within the standard MIDI protocol messages.